# nginx sites in subfolders

Tags: nginx, php

I have some trouble getting my nginx setup work the way I want. I have a site example.localhost that is located at /vagrant/frontend/www. My configuration for this, which is working, looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.localhost;

    root /vagrant/frontend/www;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

But then I want to add an admin site, located at /vagrant/backend/www, to the address example.localhost/admin. My setup is like this:

```
location /admin {
    alias /vagrant/backend/www/;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

A request to "example.localhost/admin" is processed, but when the url looks like "example.localhost/admin/site/index", it looks like the /admin location doesn't match, because the request is processed at the frontend...

I have been stuck with this for days now, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the url looks like "example.localhost/admin/site/index"

If you don't have file `/var/backend/www/site/index` your `try_files` directive last item makes internal redirect to `/index.php` which is processed by external `location ~ \.php$`

In this config I nest locations for PHP and fixed `try_files` for `/admin/` location to redirect to `/admin/index.php`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.localhost;

    root /vagrant/frontend/www;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }

    location /admin {
        return 301 /admin/;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        alias /vagrant/backend/www/;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. However, I don't get the GET values from the uri, and when I modify the try_files to "try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$args;", I get a 404 error. The error log says open() "/vagrant/frontend/wwwindex.php" failed

Comment: To be precise, when I open example.localhost/admin, the request seems to be processed correct, but if I write something like example.localhost/admin/site/index, I get the 404

Comment: Found the solution for the GET values. Change the try_files to "try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;". Then create a named location "location @handler { rewrite / /admin/index.php?$args; }"